# Website link + ctr -f shortcut

Tags: hyperlink, links, webpage, file-shortcut, shorewall

There is a specific paragraph on a webpage that I want to share with my visitors. However it takes a while to scroll down and find the text. Ctr+ f solves that issue. However, you have to do that manually. I was wonder if it is possible to make the experience smoother. As in the moment the link is clicked, the webpage automatically scroll down to the wanted paragraph. Is it possible to create a weblink+ ctr-f shortcut like that?

Comment: Yeah with auto hot key

Comment: Where is the page? Maybe it have anchors which can be used in link.